# How can I add a content part to the site in Orchard CMS and prevent the group info property from appearing in the settings menu?

Tags: c#, orchardcms

Long story short- I have a number of parts that have been welded to the site. I want to create admin screens for each of these parts, but I need to be able to choose where in the admin menu to display the links to edit them.

I have overridden the `GetItemMetadata` method in each of the handlers to add group into to the `EditorGroupInfo` collection eg:

```
    protected override void GetItemMetadata(GetContentItemMetadataContext context)
    {
        if (context.ContentItem.ContentType != "Site")
            return;
        base.GetItemMetadata(context);
        var groupInfo = new GroupInfo(T("MyNewGroup"));

        context.Metadata.EditorGroupInfo.Add(groupInfo);
    }
```

This of course will now put an item underneath settings called "MyNewGroup".

I would like to prevent this from happening so that I have the control to add this menu item where I want.

I have tried to play about with the position property of the `GroupInfo` (by setting it to "-" like in a placement.info file), but that didn't work.

Should I override `Orchard.Core.Settings.AdminMenu` and use `OrchardSuppressDependency`?

Or is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Where are you trying to add the menu item? ie. do you want these settings under the general area or something?

Comment: I want to add the items to different locations throughout the admin menu (which I know how to do). What I am asking is how to prevent these links from appearing under the "General" area of the admin menu

Comment: Editor group infos added for `Site` item will always appear underneath `Settings`. I guess overriding the class you mentioned (and suppressing the default) is the easiest way to go. Just copy it and change the current logic to exclude certain group infos.